# Couple several results in a single object

Tags: r, object

I'm writing a set of R functions that will be up online, publicly available, so I'd like to do a clean job here...for the first time.

Basically there is a function `f` that receives a dataframe and computes five real-valued numbers, call them `x1`,`x2`,`x3`,`x4` and `x5`. Then, one can call a set of other functions `g1`,`g2`,`g3` that, based on those five numbers, compute some other things. So I'd like those 5 numbers to be integrated in a single object, so to speak. Maybe even let those `g_i` functions be part of that object, like a method, or link to the original data that generated them.

Right now the `f` function just returns a vector with named entries, but I'd like it to be clean, have it's own `print` function, etc.

What is the best way to do this? I'm thinking of something similar to the `lm` function and the model objects. Are those R objects? I've never done anything like this in R, so any pointer will be much appreciated.

Comment: Check out `?list`, for a more general way to return several objects. To have your own print function, you need to add a class (see `?class`) to your return value, say, `class(x) <- "myclass"`, and define a function `print.myclass <- function(...) { do_something(...) }`.

Comment: [This answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938427/example-needed-change-the-default-print-method-of-an-object/10938565#10938565), to a similar question, might help you get started with this.

Comment: Oh, didn't know it was all done with lists. I thought you had to define S3/S4 classes and all that. Any pointer to printing tabulated data as in `summary.lm`? If you post as answer I'll accept

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of your f function returning a list? You could set it up the return bit as

```
return.list <- list(x1=x1.val , x2=x2.val, x3=x3.val, x4=x4.val, x5=x5.val)
return(return.list)
```

Then you can access the variables you want by calling `return.list$x1` and so on. This also works for returning more complicated things like data frames, tables or lists of lists.

Comment: What's wrong with just the base print.list? You get a summary by $var = val