# How can I control the output of a function in R (similar to lm)

Tags: r

I'm creating a custom function in R that takes as input a few different variables and creates a data.frame, a plot, and some summary stats, all stored in a list. I'd like to only print out the summary stats when calling the function, but have the plot and data.frame available when called explicitly.

I think what I want is similar to how `lm()` operates but I'm not sure how it is acheiving that.

When I print the object returned by `lm` I only get a printout of `$call` and `$coefficients`:

```
lm(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$cyl)

Call:
lm(formula = mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$cyl)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)   mtcars$cyl  
     37.885       -2.876
```

But clearly behind the scenes there is much more available in the function call to `lm`.

```
lm(mtcars$mpg[1:3] ~ mtcars$cyl[1:3])$residuals
            1             2             3 
-1.280530e-15  1.280530e-15  8.365277e-31 

> unclass(lm(mtcars$mpg[1:3] ~ mtcars$cyl[1:3])

Call:
lm(formula = mtcars$mpg[1:3] ~ mtcars$cyl[1:3])

Coefficients:
    (Intercept)  mtcars$cyl[1:3]  
           26.4             -0.9  


> unclass(lm(mtcars$mpg[1:3] ~ mtcars$cyl[1:3]))
$coefficients
    (Intercept) mtcars$cyl[1:3] 
           26.4            -0.9 

$residuals
            1             2             3 
-1.280530e-15  1.280530e-15  8.365277e-31 

$effects
    (Intercept) mtcars$cyl[1:3]                 
  -3.741230e+01    1.469694e+00    1.810943e-15 

....

$call
lm(formula = mtcars$mpg[1:3] ~ mtcars$cyl[1:3])

$model
  mtcars$mpg[1:3] mtcars$cyl[1:3]
1            21.0               6
2            21.0               6
3            22.8               4
```

I looked at the code for lm but it's not very clear to me what is going on.

Comment: When you call `lm()`, the output sent to the terminal is produced by a call to `print.lm()`. (It gets dispatched to by the S3 generic function `print` which looks for and finds a method for an object of class `lm`.) To see the code used by `print.lm()`, type `getAnywhere("print.lm")`. [See also here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938427/example-needed-change-the-default-print-method-of-an-object/10938565#10938565) for one example of how to develop your own custom print method.

Comment: You should look at the code for `lm` and also for `stats:::print.lm` and then read `?Methods`, I think (though it's over my head).

Comment: You have to make your list into an S3 object and create a `print` method for it. The best explained example of this is in this article I think. https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Leisch-CreatingPackages.pdf. That article shows how to create a package, the example being a simplified object similar to `lm`

Comment: To do this, you need to learn something about S3 classes and methods. This answer will get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6583265/602276

Comment: Also, if you want to explore the structure of the object created by lm (or any other) you can use `str`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The result of a call to `lm` is an object with the class attribute set to lm.  Objects of this class have their own print method (which you can call explicitly if you want using `print.lm`).  You can do something similar yourself simply by setting the class attribute of the object returned by your function and then writing your own print method.  Here's an example:

```
my.func <- function(x, y, z){
    library(ggplot2)
    df <- data.frame(x, y, z)
    p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
    ds <- sapply(df, summary)

    op <- list(data = df, plot = p, summary = ds)
    class(op) <- 'my_list'
    op
}

print.my_list <- function(m){
    print(m$summary)
}

a <- my.func(1:5, 5:1, rnorm(5))
a
print.default(a)
```

Because the list `a` has the class attribute set to `my_list`, once you have created a print method for it, this method is used whenever you print a list with that class.  You can see the entire object by explicitly calling `print.default`.  There is a very good explanation of classes in R here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html.