# Create object that is printed without quotes & \n

Tags: r

Say I have an object that is a multi-line string:

```r
object <- "value &
value"
```

I would like for the value of the object to be printed in R without “\n” and without quotes.
So instead of:

```r
object
#> [1] "value &\nvalue"
```

I would get:

```r
object
#> value &
#> value
```

This is similar to the behavior of `cat()` but I want the object to print this way by default.
I don’t want to have to call `cat()` on it. I guess I need to set a special class?

Thank you so much for your help!

<sup>Created on 2022-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You could create your own special S3 class and then then create a custom print() method for that class. But otherwise you can't change the default print behavior of a simple character value. So you want to create a custom class? Here's one such example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938427/example-needed-change-the-default-print-method-of-an-object

Comment: You might be interested in `noquote()`... though sadly it prints `\n` as-is. Otherwise, yes: `class(object) <- "printcat"; print.printcat <- function (x) cat(x); object`.

Comment: Thank you! Do you want to put this as an answer?